# Has_many and belongs_to nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I need to put a value of beauty_type_id in beauty_type form to product in nested form format. It cannot create and update beauty_type table. It is something wrong with my form or controller, so it keep roll back when save and update beauty_type.

```
class BeautyType < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :beauty_type
end

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "beauty_type_id"
end

class BeautyTypeController < ApplicationController
def new
    @beauty_type = BeautyType.new
    @beauty_type.products.build
end
def create
    @beauty_type = BeautyType.new(beauty_type_params)
    @beauty_type.save
end
private
    def beauty_type_params
      params.require(:beauty_type).permit(:title, :story, :image, :published_at, :meta_description, :meta_title, products_attributes: [:beauty_type_id, :id])

    end
    end

form:
<%= form_for(@beauty_type, :url => path, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f| %>
....
<div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.fields_for :products, @beauty_type.products do |builder| %>
      <div class='nested-fields row'>
       <%= builder.label :id, 'Product', class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
       <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= builder.select :id, Product.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, prompt: "Select something", class: "select2" %>
       <%= link_to_remove_association "remove task", builder %>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-11 right">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add task', builder, :products %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: can you post log? that you got while after submitting form

Comment: First of all above form is build to Save one BeautyType with different products, so no need to give selection for box for "beauty_type_id" it should save automatically while saving different products

Comment: error message return "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Product with ID=17 for BeautyType with ID=:"

Comment: i think no need to declare url <%= form_for(@beauty_type, :url => path, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f| %> as it's going to create

Comment: need <%= form_for(@beauty_type, :url => path, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f| %> to create other form.